# How to store large compressed CSV on S3 for use with Dask

Tags: dask

I have a large dataset (~1 terabyte of data) spread across several csv files that I want to store (compressed) on S3. I have had issues reading compressed files into dask because they are too large, and so my initial solution was to split each csv into manageable sizes. These files are then read in the following way:

```
ddf = dd.read_csv('s3://bucket-name/*.xz', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", 
                  compression='xz', blocksize=None, parse_dates=[6])
```

Before I ingest the full dataset - is this the correct approach, or is there a better way to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems sensible to me.

The only challenge that arises here is due to compression.  If a compression format doesn't support random access then Dask can't break up large files into multiple smaller pieces.  This can also be true for formats that do support random access, like xz, but are not configured to for that particular file.

Breaking up the file manually into many small files and using `blocksize=None` as you've done above is a good solution in this case.